# Reproducing a primary key clustered in ModelBuilder with several columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I am working with a table which I need to recreate in Visual Studio Core code first. The table has four keys which are clustered.   If I create the table in SQL Management Studio it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[apptmt_t](
    [acctno] [decimal](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [patno] [decimal](1, 0) NOT NULL,
    [chgslipno] [decimal](9, 0) NOT NULL,
    [sequence] [char](1) NOT NULL,

    [appt_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [appt_time_actual] [decimal](4, 0) NULL,
    [appt_time] [decimal](4, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_apptmt_t] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [acctno] ASC,
    [patno] ASC,
    [chgslipno] ASC,
    [sequence] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My entity model looks like this:

```
    [Table("apptmt_t")]
    public partial class ApptMtt
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("acctno", TypeName = "decimal(10,0)", Order = 0)]
        public decimal AcctNo { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("patno", TypeName = "decimal(1,0)", Order = 1)]
        public decimal PatNo { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("chgslipno", TypeName = "decimal(9,0)", Order = 2)]
        public decimal ChgSlipNo { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("sequence", TypeName = "char(1)", Order = 3)]
        public char Sequence { get; set; }

        [Column("appt_date", TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime? ApptDate { get; set; }

        [Column("appt_time_actual", TypeName = "decimal(4,0)")]
        public decimal ApptTimeActual { get; set; }

        [Column("appt_time", TypeName = "decimal(4,0)")]
        public decimal ApptTime { get; set; }
    }
```

In my Context file I have tried several times to get the clustering to match but I've been unsuccessful.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApptMtt>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.AcctNo).ForSqlServerIsClustered(true);
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.AcctNo).HasName("acctno");

                entity.HasKey(e => e.PatNo).ForSqlServerIsClustered(true);
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.PatNo).HasName("patno");

                entity.HasKey(e => e.ChgSlipNo).ForSqlServerIsClustered(true);
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.ChgSlipNo).HasName("chgslipno");

                entity.HasKey(e => e.Sequence).ForSqlServerIsClustered(true);
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Sequence).HasName("sequence");
                entity.Property(e => e.Sequence).IsUnicode(false);
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you want to make a primary key clustered in ModelBuilder with several columns.

You need to add the `OnModelCreating` method in your datacontext class.

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ApptMtt> Customers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Connstring");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApptMtt>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.AcctNo,c.ChgSlipNo,c.PatNo,c.Sequence });
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I updated the Context to match your example above:  

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApptMtt>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.AcctNo, e.PatNo, e.ChgSlipNo , e.Sequence});
```
When I create the SQL using migrations I get the following two lines:

```
    CONSTRAINT [PK_apptmt_t] PRIMARY KEY ([acctno], [patno], [chgslipno], [sequence]),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_apptmt_t_acctno_chgslipno_patno_sequence] UNIQUE ([acctno], [chgslipno], [patno], [sequence])
```
The first Constraint is correct, but how do I remove the second Constraint?

Comment: I realized I needed to simply delete the extra constraint line in the migration script.  That allowed my to get the correct SQL script.  Thanks!!